# How to get all $_GET parameters with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got a htaccess like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule     ^admin/$                                admin/index.php                 [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$     index.php?p=$1&id=$2             [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$                     index.php?p=$1                  [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^$                                      index.php?p=index
```

But when i get  URL like this:
`site-mine.php/product/?soomething=anything`
Then Php only realizes `product` as `$_GET` parameters.
I want to get all of it `$_GET` parameter.
could some help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the original query parameters to the rewritten url, you need the [`QSA` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa):

```
RewriteRule     ^admin/$    admin/index.php     [NC,L,QSA]    # Handle product requests
                                                      ^^^ here
# etc.
```

Comment: thank for giving me the link too. I read some tutorial but still not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `Query String Append` option

Replace

`index.php?p=$1  [NC,L]`

to

```
index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You can access GET variables as `$_GET["p"]`

> there is no space between the QSA,L. [QSA,L]